# A restriction of a closed map is a closed map?

Tags: general-topology, open-map, closed-map

$X,Y$ are topological spaces, $f:X \rightarrow Y $ is a closed map. Given a subset $B \subset Y$, let $A=f^{-1}(B) \subset X$. Prove that the restriction $g=f|_{A}:A \rightarrow B$ is a closed map. To prove that $g$ is a closed map, take a closed set of $A$, say $C'=C \cap A$ where $C$ is closed in $X$. We need to prove $g(C')$ is closed in $B$. But how can I get a new form of $g(C')$? I think it's strange, maybe can prove it in other way?  Is this a true proposition? Or give a counter example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $C$ is closed in $A$, we can write $C= C' \cap A$, where $C'$ is closed in $X$.

Now:$$g[C] = f[C'] \cap B\tag{*}$$

and as $f$ is a closed map, $g[C]$ is closed in $B$ and so $g: A \to B$ is closed.

To see $(\ast)$ is a matter of showing two inclusions, e.g.:

- If $y \in g[C]$, $y=g(x)$ for $x \in C$. So $x \in C'$ and $x \in A = f^{-1}[B]$. It follows that $g(x)=f(x) \in f[C']$ and also $g(x)=f(x) \in B$ and so $y \in f[C']\cap B$.
- If $y \in f[C'] \cap B$, write $y=f(x)$ for $x \in C'$. As $f(x)=y \in B$, $x \in f^{-1}[B]=A$ by definition, so $x \in C' \cap A= C$ and $g(x)=f(x)=y$ so $y \in g[C]$, as required.

Note that the same holds open maps $f$: $f$ open implies $g$ is open too.

Answer (score 1):

If $C\subseteq X$ is closed, then letting $p \in g(C\cap A)$ we see there exists some $q \in A\cap C$ such that $g(q) = p$.  Notice then $g(q) \in g(A)$ and $g(q) \in f(C)$ hence
$p \in g(A)\cap f(C) = B\cap f(C)$ which is closed in $B$, hence $g(A\cap C) \subseteq B\cap f(C)$.  Conversely, if $p \in B\cap f(C)$, then it is simultaneously in the inverse image of $A$ and of $C$, hence there is a $q \in A\cap C$ where $g(q) = p$, but this just implies $p \in g(A\cap C)$, proving $g(A\cap C) = B\cap f(C)$.

Comment: For g(C) to make any sense, C has to be a subset of  the domain of g, which it may not.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I've amended my answer to take care of this technicality.

Comment: Ok, prove that last equation and explain why B is closed.  Why if I write @m your name does not appear?

Comment: @WilliamElliot The reverse inclusion is proved starting when I write the word "Conversely..." If I am wrong I'll gladly delete the post, but I'd like understand why my claim is fallacious.

Comment: $f$ may not be surjective, that is why I think the condition is strange. So maybe there is no preimage of a element of $B$.

Comment: Closedness is irrelevant for the purely set-theoretical fact that when $C' \cap A=C$ we then have $g[C] = f[C'] \cap B$, see my answer.