# Continuous surjective function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^2$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness

> Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ be continuous and surjective. Show that $S=\{y\in Y:|f^{-1}(\{y\})|>1\}$ is dense.

My attempt: I assumed that $S$ is not dense, so I have an open subset $U\subset [0,1]^2$ s.t for every $y\in U$, $|f^{-1}(\{y\})|=1$, meaning $f|_{f^{-1}(U)}:f^{-1}(U)\to U$ is surjective, injective and continuous. I figured that if I show that $U=Y$, I then get a contradiction since then $f$ would be a homeomorphism, which it can't be. I tried showing that $U$ is also closed but got stuck.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is closed, since its domain is compact. Thus $f_{|f^{-1}(U)}$ is closed ([see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3615017/a-restriction-of-a-closed-map-is-a-closed-map)). This means that the inverse $g:U\to f^{-1}(U)$ is continuous. Therefore so is its composition with the inclusion $f^{-1}(U)\to \mathbb{R}$. So we get a continuous, injective map $U\to\mathbb{R}$ with $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ open. This cannot happen by [the invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).